# Complex square root integral involving the Heaviside step function.

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis

I am trying to show the following statement

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty dx \frac{f(x)}{x-a-i\eta} = \frac{a}{2} - i\sqrt{1-\frac{(a+i\eta)^2}{4}}$$

where

$$f(x) = 2 \Theta(4-x^2)\sqrt{1-x^2/4}$$

both $a$ and $\eta$ are real ($\eta > 0$) and $\Theta(x)$ is the Heaviside step function.

Does anyone know how to show the above statement?

Comment: Your expression for the integral's value is incorrect. The case $a+i\eta=i$ suggests you need $\pi$ should appear somewhere for a start.